# Extended Editing Framework -Eclipse Plugin Development

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am working on EEF (extended editing framework) and using eclipse e4 version. I have created models and editor for my ecore. I want to provide validations for my attributes which are in ecore. How can I add validations in EEF?

Comment: Could you provide some code snippets on the models you have created? Is there any specific validation you are not able to write?

Comment: I have tried the example in this below link...https://github.com/eclipse-soc/amalgamation-examples-emf/wiki/Creating-an-EEF-editor

Comment: for that ecore file , i have to provide validations. By default it provides validaitons. But i am unable to find where exactly the validaiton happens?